# Specifying multiple cultures in the AdRotator control

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone, adrotator

I am using the adRotator control with my Windows Phone 7 app.  They have a file that specifies what ads to play based on the country you are in:

```
<AdSettings> 
    <CultureDescriptors> 
        <AdCultureDescriptor CultureName="en-US"> 
            <Probabilities Probability="60" AdType="Smaato" /> 
            <Probabilities Probability="40" AdType="AdMob" /> 
        </AdCultureDescriptor> 
        <AdCultureDescriptor CultureName="en-GB"> 
            <Probabilities Probability="60" AdType="Smaato" /> 
            <Probabilities Probability="40" AdType="AdMob" /> 
        </AdCultureDescriptor> 
        <AdCultureDescriptor CultureName="de-DE"> 
            <Probabilities Probability="80" AdType="Smaato" /> 
            <Probabilities Probability="20" AdType="AdMob" /> 
        </AdCultureDescriptor> 
    </CultureDescriptors> 
</AdSettings>
```

As you can see I am specifying 3 different cultures (en-US, en-GB and de-DE).  However, 2 of them have settings that are exactly the same (en-US, en-GB).

Is there a way to specify multiple cultures on the same node?  I tried the following, but doesn't seem to work.

```
<AdSettings> 
    <CultureDescriptors> 
        <AdCultureDescriptor CultureName="en-US, en-GB, da-DK"> 
            <Probabilities Probability="60" AdType="Smaato" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no.  I've downloaded the code and looked at it - so it's a single culture per node.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why did you want to do that?

Comment: @PaulHazen I wanted to group various countries into a single XML tree.  So, for instance, I wanted to have a node for the European Union, North America, Latin America, etc...  Rather than having to create a node for each culture within it.

Answer (score 2):

[WP Unified Ad control](http://wpunifiedad.codeplex.com/) supports multiple countries in one node like following and also it provides multiple events which can help to get more controls on ads and ad space.

```
<AdCountryDescriptor Country="US, GB" InitialAdProvider="AdMob">
      <Probability Value="70" AdProvider="PubCenter" />
      <Probability Value="10" AdProvider="AdDuplex" />
      <Probability Value="10" AdProvider="MobFox" />
      <Probability Value="10" AdProvider="AdMob" />
      <Probability Value="20" AdProvider="NoAd" />
    </AdCountryDescriptor>
    <AdCountryDescriptor InitialAdProvider="PubCenter">
      <Probability Value="20" AdProvider="PubCenter" />
      <Probability Value="20" AdProvider="AdDuplex" />
      <Probability Value="20" AdProvider="MobFox" />
      <Probability Value="20" AdProvider="AdMob" />
      <Probability Value="20" AdProvider="NoAd" />
    </AdCountryDescriptor>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `CultureDescriptor` with the name of `default`. If you want common settings, then just add specific cultures that differ from the default.